# Add Dependency in Webpack Plugin

Tags: javascript, webpack

Is it possible to add a dependency from within a Webpack plugin? I'm generating files that use templates, when these templates change I'd like `webpack --watch` to trigger another build.

Here is the plugin:

```
function BlahPlugin (options) { this.options = options; }

BlahPlugin.prototype.apply = function (compiler) {

  // This is the file that I'd like to "watch"
  var template = this.options.template;

  compiler.plugin('emit', function (compilation, callback) {
    var body = Object.keys(compilation.assets).join("\n");
    require("fs").readFile(template, "utf8", function (err, data) {
      var content = data.replace("{{body}}", body);
      compilation.assets["out.txt"] = {
        source: function () { return content; },
        size:   function () { return content.length; }
      };
      callback();
    });
  });
};

module.exports = BlahPlugin;
```

This is taken from this full working project: https://gist.github.com/thatismatt/519d11b2c902791bb74b

If you run `./node_modules/.bin/webpack --watch` and modify a js file the compilation automatically triggers and produces the compiled js files and out.txt (as specified in the BlahPlugin). But if you change the tmpl.txt file, that is specified in the webpack config and used in the BlahPlugin then the compilation doesn't re-trigger. (Which is to be expected). But this is what I want to happen, how can I tell Webpack to "watch" that file?

Comment: explain your requirement bit more clearly please

Comment: @Darshan Good point, that wasn't very clear, I have updated my question. Hope you can help now. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fixed this by adding the following:

```
compiler.plugin("emit", function (compilation, callback) {
  compilation.fileDependencies.push(path.join(compiler.context, template));
  // ...
});
```

I've also update the gist, so you can see the full fix there: https://gist.github.com/thatismatt/519d11b2c902791bb74b

NOTE: this works but it is a bit of a hack.

Comment: This isn't a hack. You're free to modify the `fileDependencies` array to add any sources that need to be watched as part of this compilation.

Comment: How do you figure out the meaning of "emit" and "fileDependencies", and the right way to put them together? 
Are there ways other than debugging line by line? 

I mean I could do this, but it's way too boring. And you tend to lose the big picture along the way.

Comment: @jchnxu This document on plugin patterns may help https://webpack.js.org/contribute/plugin-patterns/ and the "emit" compiler hook is documented here: https://webpack.js.org/api/compiler-hooks/#emit

Comment: @thatismatt I hate the design because there're no encapsulation(You have to know the entire data flow to change just a little bit of s***, still you are worried about breaking other plugins). But your links are very useful!